# mail to function in PHP(using: to, from, cc, header, attachment) with validation?

Tags: php

How can i send email using mail to function using PHP with attachment and validating the email before sending it..(using: to, from, cc, header, attachment)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some helpful link to send mail using PHP, hope you can figure out yourself.

**Using PHP `mail()` function**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

**Using PHPMailer Library**

https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

**For validation**, use `filter_var` to validate emails or any data

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Examples: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php